# Installing ckeditor youtube plugin

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

Does anyone know how to extend the ckeditor to add the youtube plugin in Drupal-7?
I am talking about this plugin http://ckeditor.com/addon/youtube.
What is the drupal way of adding this?

Comment: Have you seen this post? It explains how to add a plugin using hook_wysiwyg_plugin(). https://www.drupal.org/node/848674

Comment: For D8 https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_media_embed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_mediaembed
Might be what you're looking for and it has a useful issue board if you run into trouble...